# how do i chunk a 1000MB file using mmapdemo

Tags: c, linux

I'm following a tutorial from BeeJ's website and i've learnt quite a bit of it.

I'm in that stage of experimentation and want to somehow build upon this code.

In short, say the user types an address: 1050576 for a file that's roughly 1000MB, the program (shown below) should map the chunk in the file data up to a position where 1050576 falls between chunk beginning and its length.

When i run the code, it says the max address size is 924 and so i can't really chunk a file that's 1000mb.

Could someone help explain / provide an example on how i can tackle this?

```
/*
** mmapdemo.c -- demonstrates memory mapped files lamely.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, offset;
    char *data;
    struct stat sbuf;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: mmapdemo offset\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fd = open("mmapdemo.c", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (stat("mmapdemo.c", &sbuf) == -1) {
        perror("stat");
        exit(1);
    }

    offset = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (offset < 0 || offset > sbuf.st_size-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mmapdemo: offset must be in the range 0-%ld\n", sbuf.st_size-1);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((data = mmap((caddr_t)0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == (caddr_t)(-1)) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("byte at offset %d is '%c'\n", offset, data[offset]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your file `mmapdemo.c` really 1000MB? Isn't it 924 byte?

Comment: no, it's currently 924 bytes but i want to extend it to 1000mb, but i don't know how to